# Binary Not Optimized for iPhone 5 - all icons included

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

So I was about to send my app in for review to be published on the app store, but I got this error:

[image]

I found some related StackOverflow answers that recommended that I add icon files in appropriate sizes, which I have done.

However, the build is still failing.

To add confusion to whatever is happening in this case, I have followed all instructions in the error message apple gives me and still it fails to upload:

1. I have set up UILaunchImages in my .plist file:

[image]

2. I have included an image `Default-Portrait.png` in the root level of my bundle:

[image]

So given that my launch screen and icons seem to be in order as far as the error messages describe, I am not sure what to do from here.

Any ideas what else could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify what was mentioned by @jrturton, the recommended way for iOS 8 is to create a Launch Screen, a Storyboard that you can design to adapt to various screen sizes with Auto Layout and size classes. This will be much easier than separate images for all past and future screen sizes.

[image]

Project > General:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need default-portrait~568 as well. If you're using launch images you need one for 3.5 inch screens and one for 4 inch screens.

If you use an asset catalogue for your launch images you can see exactly what is required.

Better yet, use a .xib file which will scale automatically and give you proper support for all device sizes.